# Powershell script not firing from batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0

I've been trying to launch a simple powershell script from a batch file. After looking online the advice is to set the policy using Set-ExecutionPolicy.

I've done this and using Get-ExecutionPolicy the policy has been changed.

However running this batch file results in an 'Open With' dialog rather than the execution of the script.

Batch:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe ^&'./script.psl'
```

Powershell:

```
Write-Host "This is a message"
```

I have sampled on both Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2. Both have same result. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a script file from the command line, use the -file parameter of powershell.exe.

```
 %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  -file './script.psl'
```

Comment: I get an error message doing that:

Processing -File ''./script.psl'' failed because the file does not have a '.ps1' extension. Specify a valid PowerShell script file name, and then try again.

Comment: In any case, you cannot give the file name quoted with single quotes. At least not from `cmd`. PowerShell's parsing rules apply *within* the shell, but not when invoking it with arguments.

Comment: @Tezza You'll get the `failed because the file does not have a '.ps1' extension` if, as @Joey pointed out, you single-quote the script path in Command Prompt **or** you specify a script with an extension other than `.ps1`.  In this instance both conditions are true.  Note that in your question and propagated to this answer the script extension is `.psl` instead of `.ps1` (the last character is a lowercase `L`, not the digit `1`).

Answer (score 0):

To run a script file from the *.cmd file , use the -file parameter of powershell.exe and double quotes:

```
 %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  -file "./script.ps1"
```

When you will use only one quote in batch file you can expect powershell error like:

> Processing -File ''./build.ps1'' failed because the file does not have
>   a '.ps1' extension. Specify a valid Windows PowerShell script file
>   name, and then try again.